# I want the C# program to display a table from MS ACCESS

Tags: c#, ms-access

This is an ordering system, it is our project for the finals. I want to show the rows inside the "Order" table, but it doesn't display the rows inside the table. It displayed on the "Items" table, maybe because it was the first table I made?

```
if (choice == 1)
{
    OpenCon();
    Console.WriteLine("ITEM NUMBER      ITEM                STOCK");
    Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------");

    DataTable dt = LoadData("SELECT * FROM Items");
    for (int r = 0; r < dt.Rows.Count; r++)
    {
        Console.Write(dt.Rows[r]["ItemNumber"].ToString() + "               ");
        Console.Write(dt.Rows[r]["Item"].ToString() + "                ");
        Console.Write(dt.Rows[r]["Stock"].ToString());
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    CloseCon();
}
else if (choice == 2)
{
    OpenCon();
    Console.WriteLine("ITEM NUMBER      ITEM             QUANTITY");
    Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------");
    DataTable dt2 = LoadData("SELECT * FROM Order");
    for (int i = 0; i <dt2.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(dt2.Rows[i]["ItemNumber"].ToString());
         Console.WriteLine(dt2.Rows[i]["OrderedItem"].ToString());
         Console.WriteLine(dt2.Rows[i]["Quantity"].ToString());
    }
    CloseCon();
}
```

I created a method to open and close the connection and to load the data from MS Access.

```
public static void OpenCon()
{
    con = new OleDbConnection();
    string path = @"C:\Users\Acer\Documents\OSystem.accdb";
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = " + path;
    con.Open(); 
}

public static void CloseCon()
{
    con.Dispose();
    con.Close();
}

private static DataTable LoadData(string query)
{
    adptr = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);
    cmd = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adptr);
    dTable = new DataTable();
    adptr.Fill(dTable);

    return dTable;
}
```

Comment: Fixed language and code formatting.

Comment: Terrible name for a table I'm guessing.  Try `SELECT * FROM [Order]`